# Stop a form after it has submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, dom-events

Just like the question asks, is there a way to stop a form *after* it has been submitted?

This is not a 'how do I validate' question. I cannot call a function and return true/false after some conditional. The condition on which to stop the form depends on file size, and that can only be accessed after the file has begun to be uploaded (via my form submission).

No, form submissions for file handling is *not* optimal, *but* I'm working with legacy code.

Comment: Which server-side framework are you using?

Comment: If the form data is already going to the server, you have no options. If you are using modern browsers, and have access to the File APIs, you might be able to do it using those APIs

Answer (score 0):

If by "After it has submitted", you mean "after the user has clicked on the button", a simple `return false;` or `e.stopPropagation()` is more than fit for duty.

If, however, by "After it has submitted", you mean "After the `onsubmit` event", on the client side, you are SOL. Your best bet is to do the form submission in two steps if you are dealing with legacy browsers: the file upload first, and check for returns on this... and if it worked, chain the other POST request using AJAX.

It's messy, but it's your only bet. :-(